# App Engine BadValueError On Bulk Data Upload - TextProperty being construed as StringProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, bigtable, data-import

bulkoader.yaml:

```
transformers: 
    - kind: ExampleModel 
      connector: csv 
      property_map: 
        - property: __key__ 
          external_name: key 
          export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string 
        - property: data 
          external_name: data 
        - property: type 
          external_name: type
```

model.py:

```
class ExampleModel(db.Model): 
        data = db.TextProperty(required=True) 
        type = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

Everything seems to be fine, yet when I upload I get this error:
`BadValueError: Property data is 24788 bytes long; it must be 500 or 
less. Consider Text instead, which can store strings of any length.`

For some reason, it thinks data is a string property.

Any one know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify an import transform for the text field, like this:

```
- property: data
  external_name: data
  import_transform: db.Text
```

Comment: Thanks. But now I get: Error parsing yaml file:
Unable to assign value 'db.Text' to attribute 'import_transform':
Invalid code for import_transform. Code: "db.Text". Details: name 'db' is not defined
  in "bulkloader.yaml", line 33, column 29

Comment: You need to add "from google.appengine.ext import db" to your Python imports section.

Comment: Ah! That was so simple. >_>

Thanks Nick!

Comment: Hi Nick, I've added "import_transform: db.Text" to the bulkloader.yaml but I'm still seeing an error: BadValueError: Property story_html is 3132 bytes long; it must be 500 or less. Consider Text instead, which can store strings of any length.