# Overcome appengine 500 byte string limit in python? consider text

Tags: python, string, google-app-engine, text, limit

I get this:

```
BadValueError: Property   is 804 bytes long; it must be 500 or less. Consider Text instead, which can store strings of any length.
```

I read this: http://blog.zmxv.com/2012/02/appengine-go-sdks-500-byte-string.html and this: [App Engine BadValueError On Bulk Data Upload - TextProperty being construed as StringProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434090/app-engine-badvalueerror-on-bulk-data-upload-textproperty-being-construed-as-s) but I still don't understand how to solve it quickly.

It says, consider text? I'm willing to consider text!:)

If I limit user input to 500 chars, will that solve everything? Thanks..

Comment: this error message said there is at least one of your models defined a string property but accepted some string more than 500 bytes. You just need to correct the definition to a text property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

so consider the `TextProperty`.

switch from.

```
yourproperty = db.StringProperty()
```

to

```
yourproperty = db.TextProperty()
```

and you will be fine. keep in mind that `TextProperty` is **not indexed**.

Comment: Not indexed as in can't be searched by?
That is ok, I don't search by strings.. is that it? :)