# Traceback when I use urllib2, get a HTTP 500 error

Tags: python, urllib2

My code is like follows, but when it runs it throws an error.

```
search_request = urllib2.Request(url,data=tmp_file_name,headers={'X-Requested-With':'WoMenShi888XMLHttpRequestWin'})
#print search_request.get_method()
search_response = urllib2.urlopen(search_request)
html_data = search_response.read()
```

the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xx_tmp.py", line 83, in <module>
    print hello_lfi()
  File "xx_tmp.py", line 69, in hello_lfi
    search_response = urllib2.urlopen(search_request)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_defau
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

I don't know how to fix it? I mean, when an error happened, how can my code continue to work?

when i try use

```
       try:
                search_response = urllib2.urlopen(search_request)
            except urllib2.HTTPError:
                pass
```

new error

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'search_response' referenced before assignment
```

i use

```
global search_response
```

and have error

```
NameError: global name 'search_response' is not defined
```

Comment: The server didn't like your request, this is not a python problem.

Comment: This is the problem with the Server you are sending the request to and not with `urllib2` try another url.

Comment: You can [catch the exception](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) but that won't give you any useful information from the server.

Comment: yeah,i konw this is a server problem,i mean is when this error happened,how can program go on work

Comment: Don't edit the question to ask something completely different; ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the exception, this will prevent your program from stopping so 'abruptly':

```
try:
  search_response = urllib2.urlopen(search_request)
except urllib2.HTTPError:
  print 'There was an error with the request'
```

If you want to continue, you can simply:

```
try:
  search_response = urllib2.urlopen(search_request)
except urllib2.HTTPError:
  pass
```

This will allow your program to continue; but your other statement `html_data = search_response.read()` won't give you the expected result.  To fix this problem permanently, you need to debug your request to see why its failing; this isn't something specific to Python.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I was trying to send a large post request to my GAE Python server. It turns out the server threw the error because I was trying to write the received POST string into a db.StringProperty(). I changed that to db.TextProperty() and it didn't throw the error anymore.

Source: [Overcome appengine 500 byte string limit in python? consider text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178869/overcome-appengine-500-byte-string-limit-in-python-consider-text)

Comment: Remember, TextProperty() isn't an indexed field in the datastore.